# ASP.NET Wizard control header template help needed

Tags: asp.net, wizard

I found a link given below:

[**CLICK HERE**](http://techbrij.com/798/stylish-asp-net-wizard-control-horizontal-sidebar-on-top)

I have to implement this header template in asp.net application but the problem is that it's not work properly in IE8.

Is there any way to make it work in IE8.

**Other than IE8**

[image]

**In IE8**

[image]
Thanks

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: what screenshot you are talking about,actually the given link provide to everything

Comment: i use the same header and it seems to be only a rendering issue. Instead of arrows rectangles are shown. I think this i a thing the user can live with :) At least for me.

Comment: Please see the screenshot.later one is in IE8 which is not acceptable for my client.Do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS transform does not work with IE6, IE7 or IE8. (skewx)

You can use transparent png's as a background image but that will work only for IE8. You will have to use pngfix for transparent pngs in IE<8.

Answer (score 0):

Check here:
http://www.emirplicanic.com/css/css-step-by-step-menu-wizard-style

It will work fine on IE 9 and IE8, and looks better on IE7.